# How does compareValuesBy() work in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Here's the declaration from the kotlinlang.org:

```
        fun <T> compareValuesBy(
        a: T,
        b: T,
        vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>?
    ): Int
```

1. Comparable is an interface, how can you return an interface?
2. What does the spread operator * do in Comparable<*>?

In the example demonstrating the function:

```
    fun compareLengthThenString(a: String, b: String): Int =
    compareValuesBy(a, b, { it.length }, { it })
```

What does 'it' refer to? a or b?
Thank you for reading.

**Update**

```
    class Person(
    val firstName: String, val lastName: String
    ) : Comparable<Person> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Person): Int {
    return compareValuesBy(this, other,
    Person::lastName, Person::firstName)
    }
    }
```

As you can see, the last two arguments are not lambdas, but it works. Why? compareValuesBy requires a lambda there but two references to a property are passed in.

Comment: This isn't really a question about `compareValuesBy`, it's asking for explanation of Kotlin language features. 1) Polymorphism 2) Generics and 3) Lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offical docs: [`compareValuesBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-values-by.html).

1. You can't return an interface. What it means is that the `selectors` function must return an instance of an object that *implements* the `Comparable<*>` interface.
2. That is not the spread operator, but a wildcard type parameter. `Comparable<T>` is a generic interface. Here it's saying that it doesn't care what the value of `T` is (i.e. it can be anything).
3. `it` refers to the argument passed in to the lambda. In this case, the lambdas are called with *both* `a` and `b`, and the returned values are compared. So `a.length` is compared to `b.length`. If they are the same, the values of `a` and `b` are compared directly (the second `{ it }` lambda).

Comment: `(T) -> Comparable<*>?` specifies a **function** that accepts `T` and returns `Comparable<*>?`. There are many ways to pass a function as a parameter, lambda is one of them. But you can also use anonymous functions, and function references. `Person::lastName` is a function reference. It refers to the `lastName` method of the `Person` class. So it's saying compare `Person` by `lastName` then `firstName`.

Comment: ☝️ In reply to the OP's comment that has vanished 

Comment: I am sorry Adam Millerchip. Please see the update. And no. Person::lastName is a string.

Comment: I answered your follow-up question in the comment above.

Comment: Please read again. Person::lastName and Person::firstname are strings as far as I know. The Person class has only one function, ie compareTo.

Comment: No, they are property references. It translates to: "Compare `this.lastName` and `other.lastName`, then `this.firstName` and `other.firstName`".

Comment: You could also write it with lambdas: `compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.lastName }, { it.firstName })`. `{ it.lastName }` is a function that takes a `Person` and returns a `String`. So is `Person::lastName`.

Comment: And for those who may be interested in a detailed discussion of my #2 question, there's a wonderful article here: [link](https://typealias.com/guides/star-projections-and-how-they-work/)